# takeLatest$1 requires a saga parameters

Tags: ecmascript-6

***Problem***

Hello to all, I'm tryin to use redux-saga and as the title said I have the error

```
takeLatest$1 requires a saga parameters
```

I don't know what I'm missing, and I didn't find anything related on the internet.

***Code***

Below you will find the file `saga/index.js`

```
import {
  GET_NEWS_REQUEST,
} from '../types';
import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { fetchRecords } from './apiCallSaga';

export default function* root() {
  yield takeLatest(GET_NEWS_REQUEST, fetchRecords,);
}
```

in the same folder I've the file `saga/apiCallSaga.js`

```
import { put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { getNewsSuccess, getNewsFailed } from '../actions';

function* fetchRecords() {

  const url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?'

  try {
    const response = yield fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
    console.log(response);
    yield put(getNewsSuccess(response));
  } catch (e) {
    yield getNewsFailed();
  }
}; 

export default { fetchRecords };
```

***Expected Behaviour***

I need to make the call to a link ( the one provided isn't complete ). This error shouldn't appear.

Comment: i can post the other related files if they are useful ( actions and type, but i don't think this error is linked to this two files )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i found the answer.

The problem was

```
export default
```

i need only to

```
export { fetchRecords };
```

Comment: Since this was ES6 modules issue instead of a redux-saga issue, I suggest to update tags and summary.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same error with the `reduxsauce` package and typescript and I keep landing this question.

```
export default function* root() {
  yield takeLatest(GET_NEWS_REQUEST, fetchRecords,);
}
```

In order to prevent above from throwing You need to createActions like below;

```
const {
  Types,
  Creators
}: CreatedActions<ActionTypes, DefaultActionCreators> = createActions({
  getNewsRequest: null
});
```